# FlaUI reference a button by a Control instead of a string

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization, visual-studio-2022, flaui

I want to find a way to instead of calling the button by name "Add" on line 26, to be called by the control instead. something like `nameof(AddButton)` or something of the like.

this code is in a test project that is in the same solution as my winform and it has a project reference to it.

```
using FlaUI.Core;
using FlaUI.UIA2;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestFormRevisitedTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UITest
    {
        string _folderPath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\testPhotos\";


        [TestMethod]
        public void AddButtonAutomation()
        {
            var app = Application.Launch("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Self-Study\\TestFormRevisited\\TestFormRevisited\\bin\\Debug\\net7.0-windows\\TestFormRevisited.exe");

            try
            {
                using (var automation = new UIA2Automation())
                {
                    var mainWindow = app.GetMainWindow(automation);

                    if (mainWindow != null)
                    {
                        var button = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(b => b.ByName("Add"));
                        var screenBeforeClick = mainWindow.Capture();

                        if (button != null)
                            button.Click();

                        var screenAfterClick = mainWindow.Capture();




                        screenBeforeClick.Save(Path.Combine(_folderPath, "before_click.png"));
                        screenAfterClick.Save(Path.Combine(_folderPath, "after_click.png"));
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                app.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting calling the controls with

```
var mainForm = new TestFormRevised();
var controls = mainForm.Controls;
```

but i don't think it does what i think it does and i couldn't call on the exact buttons and other controls i needed